# how to use execvp() in C to sort a file and write into another file

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec, execvp

Suppose I have temp.txt in my home directory, I want to sort all the data in this file, and write all the sorted data into another file named hello.txt. Here is my code(programming c) I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int agrc,char *argv[]){
    char *argv1[]={"sort","temp.txt",">", "hello.txt",NULL};
    printf("hello I will sort a file\n");

    execvp(argv1[0],argv1);



}
```

Here is my program,the terminal always gives me an error message which is

```
hello I will sort a file
sort: cannot read: >: No such file or directory
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Can someone tell me how to fix it? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type `sort temp.txt > hello.txt` to the shell, you are *not* passing `>` and `hello.txt` as arguments to `sort`.  But when you invoke `execvp` as above, you *are* passing those as arguments to sort.  If you want the shell to treat `>` as a redirection operator, you need to pass the string to `sh` and let it evaluate it:

```
char *argv1[]={ "sh", "-c", "sort temp.txt > hello.txt", NULL };
```

The 'proper' way to do this is to do the redirection yourself by duping file descriptors.  Something like (some error checking omitted for clarity):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int fd;
    const char *input = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "temp.txt";
    const char *output = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "hello.txt";
    char * argv1[] = { "sort", input, NULL };

    fd = open( output, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777 );
    if( fd == -1 ) {
        perror(output);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("hello I will sort a file\n");
    fclose(stdout);
    dup2( fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd);
    execvp(argv1[0],argv1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it is very helpful!